# Problem with types with ts, useStorage (vueuse) and Pinia

Tags: typescript, vue.js, local-storage, pinia

I'm getting a weird error in the following code:  `Property 'length' does not exist on type '{ [RefSymbol]: true; }'.`

But when I check the type of `foo` in the getCount function my IDE tels me its of type `Foo[]`. What am I doing wrong?

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { useStorage } from '@vueuse/core';

interface Foo {}

export const useFooStore = defineStore('foo', {
  state: () => ({
    foo: useStorage('foo', [] as Foo[]),
  }),
  actions: {
    getCount() {
      return this.foo.length; //Here's the error
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Your code [seems to show no type errors](https://tsplay.dev/m35D1w) (if I provide a type for `Job`). Can you create a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the problem>

Comment: @AlexWayne That's very weird. I changed it to the minimal reproducible code that you asked for... but it looks a lot like what you wrote, without errors. My IDE isn't showing any errors, only when I try to compile the typescript it happens.

Answer (score 3):

I think the return value of `useStorage` isn't what you think. I believe it returns a ref, of sorts, with a `value` property that contains the actual data being stored.

Try:

```
useStorage('jobs', [] as Job[]).value
```

Comment: Yes it does, but that's what I need it to be. In the actions part I expect to be able to work on the value though

Answer (score 0):

Now there is not very much info in your post but from what the error message says I'd guess the following. You are defining an object with the type

```
{ [RefSymbol]: true; }
```

but as length does not exist on your type I think an array is beeing expected for jobs?

Comment: Yes, my IDE tells me its an array of type Job... but the ts compiler thinks differently

Comment: My IDE isn't showing any errors, but the website isn't running

Answer (score 0):

When I prepend the line with the error with

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment */
// @ts-ignore
return this.foo.length; //Here used to be the error
```

Then it suddenly works. It's hella ugly, but it works